# Current Feedback on a SVPWM board

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, power-electronics, motor-controller, vector-control

So I have developed a SVPWM board and an open loop control to run an AC motor. The board and firmware have been tested and the motor runs perfectly on an open loop control. Now I want to use current feedback from the motors and convert this into a current control closed loop. I am using an LSPR 15-NP current transducer for this purpose.

Now according to the datasheet the current transducer is supposed to give me 0-5 Vrms output. The reference voltage used is internal, therefore at Ia=0 A the voltage will be 2.5 V at the output. After connecting my motor load I can see that the Vrms is changing but it has a lot of variation. The variation ranges from 2.403 V to 3.057 V. Now, this variation is also being reflected on my controller but I cannot work with this kind of data. I need a constant Vrms to implement my current loop, I think.

My question is why I am getting such variation and how can I make it smooth so that I can implement my current control closed loop? I have tried averaging upto 30 values in my code but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome.  To get good answers you need to me provide more details, such as schematics, waveform traces, picture of overall setup.